# Compare two variables of one node

Tags: r, network-programming, social-networking

I am doing a network analysis and my nodes have different variables ascribed to them. Is there a way to compare how the different variables are connected to each other? Or asked another way: How can I compare how many of the nodes have the same pair of values concerning the variables?

I don't know if this is enough, but as follows is part of the csv-file I'm working with. My question is if there is a way to calculate the correlation of the variables TS, PO and Art.

```
ID;label;TS;PO;Art
https://agensev.de;https://agensev.de;MR;Konservativ;Organisation
https://bundesforum-maenner.de/;https://bundesforum-maenner.de/;MR;Progressiv;Organisation
https://www.familien-schutz.de/;https://www.familien-schutz.de/;Familie;Extreme Rechte;Kampagne
https://fsi-ev.de/;https://fsi-ev.de/;MR;Konservativ;Organisation
https://genderama.blogspot.com;https://genderama.blogspot.com;MR;Liberal;Blog
https://www.genderkongress.org;https://www.genderkongress.org;MR;Konservativ;Kongress
https://www.genug-traenen.de;https://www.genug-traenen.de;Kinder;Konservativ;Kampagne
https://jungsundmaedchen.wordpress.com;https://jungsundmaedchen.wordpress.com;MR;Liberal;Blog
https://manndat.de;https://manndat.de;MR;Liberal;Organisation
https://vaeteraufbruch.de;https://vaeteraufbruch.de;MR;Liberal;Organisation
https://wgvdl.com;https://wgvdl.com;MR;Extreme Rechte;Blog
http://cuncti.net/;http://cuncti.net/;Nachrichten;Extreme Rechte;Alt. Medien
```

I couldn't find a function for this yet, but it seems quite a simple issue to me. Maybe someone has a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I exchanged the random example with some of the data I am working with. I hope this makes it easier to understand. If not, please explain which kind of code is needed, because at the moment I don't have any other (sorry, I'm still new to R and questions around it).